# Implementation of a saturation function in Simulink/Matlab

Tags: matlab, simulation, simulink

I am making a Simulink/Matlab control model, however, I am unsure on how to implement the following  as a Simulink block:

[saturation function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zETfX.png)

Where v(t) is the input of the saturation function, u_0 is a constant and u is the output.

I looked at the saturation and saturation dynamic blocks, however, I am unsure how to implement a dynamic output with a constant limit.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement it using either of the blocks you mentioned (saturation and saturation dynamic).

Attached image shows how to use the Saturation Dynamic block to model your equations. Input signal `v` will be truncated to either `+u0` or `-u0` if its amplitude is larger than `u0`. In this implementation saturation limit `u0` is constant as you requested. For a dynamic saturation limit you can drive `up` and `lo` block inputs with any other signal.

[image: Saturation Dynamic usage]